# How to add a button to the end of row programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using datagrid in WPF, data is binded successfully but I need to add a button to the end of row. For example if status = 1 then add button with red color and content like "Not confirmed", and if status != 1 then add button with blue color and content like "See details"

Updated  :

```
    if(status == "1")
                    {
                        //add a button to the end of row with red color and content 


                        foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        {
                           tb.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));
                            foreach (DataRow row in tb.Rows)
                            {
                                r["ButtonColumn"] = new Button
                                {
                                    Name = "rowButton",
                                    Content = "Row Button Content",
                                    Width = 100,
                                    Height = 30
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        stock_details.ItemsSource = new DataView(result.Tables["STOCK_OFFICER"]);
                    }else if(status != "1")
                    {
                        //add a button to the end of row with blue color and content 
                        tb.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));

                        foreach (DataTable dtb in result.Tables)
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow ro in tb.Rows)
                            {
                                r["ButtonColumn"] = new Button
                                {
                                    Name = "rowButton",
                                    Content = "Second Button",
                                    Width = 100,
                                    Height = 30
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        stock_details.ItemsSource = new DataView(result.Tables["STOCK_OFFICER"]);
                    }
```

how can I do that using the current code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is the code you're looking for.
Add a new column for the button in your data table. Fill that column with a button for each row. You can also add a click event handler and execute the button functionality accordingly.

```
tb.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));

foreach(DataTable tb  in result.Tables)
{
    foreach(DataRow r in tb.Rows)
    {
        r["ButtonColumn"] = new Button
                {
                    Name = "rowButton",
                    Content = "Row Button Content",
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 30
                };
        tb.Rows.AddRow(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to add this `dt.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));` to current data table ? ca

Comment: It might be `tb.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));`

Comment: I have updated my code, but it didnt add any button! please look to updated question code

Comment: You should add the column to datatable. ie after this line `foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        {` as `dt.Columns.Add("ButtonColumn", typeof(Button));`

Comment: Add that row to the datatable again `tb.Rows.AddRow(r);` and check. I updated the answer.